# Change Email From Direction in C#

Tags: c#, email, automation, ms-office

I got my outlook configured with 2 emails. My personal email and a mailbox.
Federico@outlook.com
Mailbox@outlook.com

Have tried this already(code below), but its sending emails from Federico@outlook.com instead of Mailbox@outlook.com

```
 private static void CreateMailItem(String to,String subject,string body)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItem = app.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
            mailItem.To = to;
            mailItem.Subject = subject;
            mailItem.Body = body;
            mailItem.Display(false);
            mailItem.Send();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `SendUsingAccount` ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem?view=outlook-pia)) ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-send-a-mail-item-by-using-a-hotmail-account))

*SendUsingAccount
Returns or sets an Account object that represents the account under which the MailItem is to be sent. Read/write.
(Inherited from _MailItem)*

So just add:

```
Outlook.Account account = Application.Session.Accounts["Hotmail"]; //or however your other account is indexed in your accounts list
mail.SendUsingAccount = account;
```